# How to know an operation has definitely been included?

Tags: taquito

For example, calling an entrypoint to change a smart contract's storage. When can I be maximally certain the change is now part of the blockchain? Will it suffice if I grab the contract's storage with Taquito and see my change there?

A link to official docs to support your answer would be desirable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The change to a smart contract is definitely part of the blockchain when one block has been added on top of the contract call. See https://tezos.gitlab.io/active/consensus.html#transaction-and-block-finality for the details.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're asking on how to check whether the op has now been injected or not in Taquito, since that's what you tagged it with.

In Taquito, when you call a certain contract entrypoint, like so:

```
const op = await contract.methods.default().send();
```

You should then do what's called a 'confirmation':

```
await op.confirmation();
```

That method basically confirms that your operation now has been injected properly.

If you want the results of your operation, you can also see them by outputting the operation results:

```
console.log(await op.operationResults());
```

For more examples, you can definitely check out some that we wrote here: https://github.com/ecadlabs/taquito/tree/master/example

Comment: `op.confirmation()` accepts an optional numeric argument. Your answer implies it is obsolete, such as for obsolete tezos protocols. (This topic is confusing because there's a lot of obsolete info on the internet about this.)

Comment: Davis' answer implies it is optional, not obsolete. Building on Raphaël's answer, you should use `await op.confirmation(2);` to be 100% sure the change has been included in the Tezos blockchain, Taquito will wait for 2 blocks before returning the confirmation.